# Cannot deselect elements in jquery-sortable after scrolling (chrome)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Bit of a weird bug with the jQuery-UI sortable (using latest stable jQuery & jQuery ui).

Essentially if one of the sortable elements contains a scrollbar (max-height + scroll:auto), after using the scroll bar it becomes very difficult to drop the item again (as this action will result in the item being selected.)

As far as i can tell the issue only effects chrome (firefox at the very least does not appear to share it).

I've put together a slightly awful demo of the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/shVFX/ If you attempt to scroll the long item in chrome it will stick to your cursor.

Has anyone encountered this issue before / have any ideas on how i may be able to mitigate it? (being able to scroll through sortable items would be a pretty useful feature for the project I'm working on.)

Thanks :)

Other details:
Using chrome: v22.0.1 (beta channel)
jQuery 1.8.1 cdn
jQuery-UI 1.8.23 cdn

Answer (score 1):

We had also faced the same issue with vertical scroll bar and solved it. Please find the solution in the below URL. The trick is "handle: '.sort'"

```
$(function() {
$('.sort').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sort',
    handle: '.sort'
    scroll : false,
});
```

});​

Also find demo of the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/PrZNr/44/